# My firebase int returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull an int from my firebase db however when I try and set my variable it returns nil.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()    
let UserUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as? String

ref.child("users").child(UserUID!).child("MaxVal").observeSingleEvent(of:
.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snap = snapshot.value as? Int
            self.MaxValFB = snap! //this returns nil

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Any help apreiciated!

EDIT: upon printing its result it returns 
     Optional( null)

also here is the db json file
    `{
  "users" : {
    "Optional(\"njcfCQaIIhZS9qrqM9OFLqTS7yA2\")" : {
      "MaxVal" : 1
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Did you tried printing what value do you get from Snapshot I think it will be something like [value], Can you please show snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this `"Optional(\"njcfCQaIIhZS9qrqM9OFLqTS7yA2\")"` , when you are saving the data to firebase , you are giving it the id without unwrapping the optional and when you get the value you are unwrapping it like `UserUID!` , so it gives `"njcfCQaIIhZS9qrqM9OFLqTS7yA2"` , hence these are two different values.

So I think you should unwrap the userid when you save the data to firebase or try to get it without unwrapping i.e `child(UserUID)` without `!` , although I would suggest to go with the first option.